# Is it possible to send routing directions to the HereWeGo app?

Tags: here-api

We are trying to allow people to open their navigation app to show the one or more addresses that we already have set up for them. Is this possible with the HereWeGo app? The reason why we don't use Google maps for this is due to the fact they are driving in trucks and there HereWeGo App supports this.

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

The HERE WeGo service does not offer Truck routes as an option, the only options available are:

- Car
- Public transport
- Pedestrian
- Taxi

You can visit the HERE WeGo website at the following link so you can review all of its features: https://wego.here.com/

Similarly, we are pleased to tell you that we provide the Truck routing service through our Routing v8 API or if you prefer, we still have SDKs available that can be adjusted to what you need to do.

We invite you to take a walk through our documentation to learn more about these services:

- https://developer.here.com/documentation
- https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/index.html

Best regards!